# How to put Wamp Online?

Tags: wamp

I have wamp installed on my pc. and i have used the put online option. But when i visit my ip address. it doesnt visit my local host. on my desktop it used to happen. when i got my laptop. not it redirects to my Router Modems login page.

How to set wamp to access it via my ip address.

Comment: Have you set up port forwarding to direct the port you are running wamp on to the IP address of your computer?

Comment: i use this modem UTSTARCOM WA3002G4. not sure how to do it can u help me.

Comment: http://variable3.com/files/screenshots/2010-10-02_0210.png

Comment: possible duplicate: [Making home based web server](http://superuser.com/questions/336280/making-home-based-web-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP port forwarding on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/523674/wamp-port-forwarding-on-windows-7)