# Setting up a WEB server at home

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

I have apache2 installed and have subscribed to no-ip (similar to dyndns) to get a static IP. When I enter the IP they have provided,it takes me to the DSL router page of my ISP as it should. My question is how do I redirect it to my var/www folder so that my PC in converted to a web server. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: [Making home based web server](http://superuser.com/questions/336280/making-home-based-web-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should configure NAT on your router and forward port 80 (and/or 443) to the 'internal' IP. How depends on your router.

On a side note I would disallow access to your router configuration by external IP addresses (i.e., you router configuration page should not be visible from the outside)

Comment: Off topic here, but I tend to disable the ability to administer the router wirelessly as well.

Comment: @Melikoth Great tip.

Comment: What exactly is meant by internal IP? The IP of localhost(127.0.0.1) ?

Comment: @amalantony no, most likely your router is releasing IP addresses in a private range (e.g., 192.168.*.*). These addresses are only valid in your home network. Which is the IP address of your server?

Comment: Yes .. it's 192.168.2.3 . Is that my internal IP?

Comment: I use an external program called guidedog for port forwarding, whereby I send packets received via TCP port 80 to port 80 of 192.168.2.3 . However, the no-ip address still directs to DSL config page? any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @amalantony No the forwarding has to be performed by the router. From the outside the only visible thing is your router. An external machine connects to the router (external IP) which forwards the packets to your machine. This is not automatic, has to be configured in the router.

Comment: The software works by editing the routing tables , so the result is the same isnt it? Moreover my router only has an option for DMZ under NAT which I set to my internal IP as you suggested. It still doesnt redirect to my www folder.

Comment: DMZ is a bad option in of itself... Your public IP (assigned by your ISP) will get redirected to your server. You should never DMZ unless you want your computer hacked. Only open ports that you purposely will use.

Comment: Presumably, the only thing you want redirected is port 80. Your router should have the option to redirect requests on port 80 to "192.168.2.3". "2.3" should have the firewall tuned to let port 80 in (hopefully you have a firewall). Apache should be listening to port 80. Add 443 if you want to get HTTPS working.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your apache setup is working. Now you need to forward port 80/443 from your dsl router to you system's internal ip address. So when router received request on port 80/443 it will forward it to your server.

Read documentation of you router on how to do port forwarding.