# WAMP port forwarding on Windows 7

Tags: wamp, router, port-forwarding

I have a problem with port forwarding. I run on Windows 7. I have installed WAMP on my PC and I want to put it online. I disabled my firewall, apply port forwarding on my router (in my case: 8343 to 80), put WAMP online and when I go to `myip:8343` my browser say that it cannot access this address.

1. Does someone know what can be the pb?
2. Does someone know how can I test if the router forward the request to my specific port alternatively than see the response in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the pb...

- Set DMZ host at your LAN ip
- Set your wamp to listen to 8080 and restart service.
- from an external network go to your public_ip:8080 it's should be work...

Comment: I realize this answer is very old, but this is a terrible idea. Some routers do not have "NAT reflection" (aka "NAT loopback") enabled. This means that forwarded ports cannot be accessed from inside the local network. This is what most likely raised this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the web server is bounded to localhost.

You can check if it is bound to localhost by executing `netstat -an` in a command prompt.
If it is bounded to localhost,you'll see a 127.0.0.1:80 in the local adress column.

See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html) for documentation on configuring the address binding of apache.

As for the 2nd part of your question, I would suggest [Netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).

I have always used it for TCP/IP troubleshooting.They don't call it "The TCP/IP Swiss army knife" for nothing!

You can find a windows port [here](http://joncraton.org/files/nc111nt.zip).

Check [here](http://www.binarytides.com/check-port-forwarding-with-netcat/) for a simple guide of using Netcat to check port forwarding.

Comment: no its not...  0.0.0.0:80

Comment: when you say myip:8343 you mean your public IP,right?

Comment: yes of course !

Comment: thank you for your response i'll try it(netcat) !
if you have an another solution for my first issue i will be happy...