# How access my computer with ip?

Tags: windows-7, ip

I have wireless network connection with ip xxx.92.107.xx(from http://www.whatismyip.com/) and internal ip xxx.168.0.10. I have cisco router with this setting[image]. I turned on wamp server
I want to get access via this ip  xxx.92.107.xx. I didn't grt access. But i can ping this ip in cmd. How access my wamp server remotely?

Comment: Kinda pointless to hide the `192` in `192.168.0.10`. `192.168.0.0` through `192.168.255.255` is [reserved for private networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) and is used by 99% of most home routers. (the other 1% using `10.0.0.0` through `10.255.255.255`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP port forwarding on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/523674/wamp-port-forwarding-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left click wamp tray icon and choose Put Online. Make sure you have allowed full access to port 80 in your firewall. If your using a router you'll need to configure it to forward all port 80 connections to your computers LAN address, eg 192.168.0.10

For port forwarding instructions go to [portforward.com](http://portforward.com/)

All you should be able to do now is give your IP address to your friend and he should able to connect you. If your ip address is dynamic (meaning it changes offen) sign up to a free account at dyndns.com

Keep in mind you should secure it once you put it out there. [Secure Wamp Server](http://securitymecca.com/article/install-and-secure-a-wamp-webserver/)

[Answer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,62109,62113)

Answer (score 0):

> **How access my computer with ip?**

http://xxx.92.107.xx:70/

where xxx and xx are replaced with the actual numbers which you obscured and which, together,  represent the external IP-address of your Internet router.

If this doesn't work there are many possible causes including.

- Your router isn't actually configured the way you think it is.
- Your router has other rules which negate your attempt at port forwarding
- Your webserver isn't actually running
- Your webserver isn't listening on the port you think it is
- Your webserver isn't bound to the internal IP address of the computer's ethernet interface
- Your webserver configuration prohibits non-local requests
- etc

If your external IP address varies from time to time you may want to register an external domain or make use of a dynamic dns service (some of which are free) then you can use `http://my-registered-domain.com` or `http://messi-fan.some-dynamic-dns-provider.com` respectively.