# How to access a WAMP server site outside of my network?

Tags: wamp

The server is in online mode and I can connect to it with `http://(ip)` and `http://localhost`. IP method works with other computers in my network too.

Anything outside my network can not connect to it. How can I set this up?

Comment: Did you port forward your router?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP port forwarding on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/523674/wamp-port-forwarding-on-windows-7)

Comment: I am not sure who down voted both answers, but they are both correct.

Answer (score -1):

Considering you are using your external IP address to connect to the server, Are you on your home network connection or on a business connection? If on an home network, most home ISPs block incoming access to port 80 and other commonly used services. This is both to prevent home users from using their connection for commercial purposes and to safeguard users against attacks if a service is running in home network.

Check if port is open by using [this online tool.](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

Also you can temporarily switch the server to serve over a different port that is not blocked (usually anything over 1000 works) and see if you can now view your page.

Also, have you configured port forwarding to forward affected ports to your server? This is required to connect to your server from external client. Steps for this differs by router make and model but you should find the `port forwarding` setting and configure it to forward external port 80 or 443 to the correct ports on your server

Answer (score -1):

To access a server from outside of your network you need to port forward on your router, how this is achieved on different routers varies and you would need to look at your routers documentation or look that up online.

But what you need to do is:

Point the dns A record for the domain name to your public IP address. This is done where you registered the domain name.

Port forward 80 and 443(ssl) to the local IP address assigned to your server, this is done on your router, (some routers let you assign the port forward to a connected host others only to an ip address).

Check that any firewall on the server allows access from anywhere to those two ports, again you will need to search how to do that for your specific firewall.

Once all this is set up, if you still cannot connect it might be that you have not set the server up to listen on those ports or that your residential ISP has blocked those ports to prevent running a web server on their network. There are ways around that but it would likely break your contract with them if they don't permit it.